# Is there a way to place 3 List strings into another List<>?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to place 3 List strings into another List<>?

Starting with:

```
List<???> listTableNames = new List<???>();
List<string> liststTable1 = new List<string>();
List<string> liststTable2 = new List<string>();
List<string> liststTable3 = new List<string>();
listTableNames.Add(liststTable1);
listTableNames.Add(liststTable2);
listTableNames.Add(liststTable3);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make a list where each element is a list of strings?  That's `List<List<string>>`. If that's not what you're asking, can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric Lippert provided the answer in the comments.

```
List<List<string>> listTableNames = new List<List<string>>();
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this help you** , using `AddRange` method:

```
List<string> listTableNames = new List<string>();
List<string> liststTable1 = new List<string>();
List<string> liststTable2 = new List<string>();
List<string> liststTable3 = new List<string>();

listTableNames.AddRange(liststTable1);
listTableNames.AddRange(liststTable2);
listTableNames.AddRange(liststTable3);
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/v7LocY)